# Sails.js Can I add sort functionality to default find action without overriding it?

Tags: sails.js

I was just curious to know if it's by any means possible to add a sort functionality to the default find action of a model without overriding the same in the controller ?

We do have beforeCreate and afterCreate features in the models which is quite useful in many cases. Similarly beforeFetch or something like that, if exists can be really useful when we want some pre/post processing on the result set while doing a get request.

Comment: Do you mean like http://localhost:1337/user?sort=id desc

Comment: exactly, thanks!! I could not find it in docs. Where did you find this ? Also, how do I sort in descending order ?

Comment: ASC or DESC I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of this would be:  localhost:1337/user?sort=id desc